# Hide submit button until a file has been chosen through pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, input

I want to show the submit button only after a file is selected. I can do this with jQuery but I have not used jQuery in any part of the page so to avoid some spaces I need this to be done through pure JavaScript.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="pimage"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const submitButton = form.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
const inputFile = form.querySelector('[type="file"]');

inputFile.addEventListener('change', () => {
    submitButton.style.display = inputFile.files.length ? '' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="pimage"/> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" style="display: none">
</form>
```

Comment: How can we select form using its id and input fields with id?

Comment: Use `document.getElementById(id)` or `document.querySelector(#id)`. Here id is the the id you want to select.